# VisionOS - How to navigate between SwiftUI Views?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, visionos

I'm trying to build a simple VisionOS app with a single window and i wanna navigate between SwiftUI Views by tapping a custom View embedded inside a NavigationLink as I always did with all SwiftUI apps.

The issue is that nothing happens when I tap on the view, here is the code:

```
 NavigationLink {
      TheViewIWantNavigate()
    } label: {
      MyCustomView()
 }
```

I was able to recognize the tap with this code:

```
HomeButtonView(text: "Tap Here", image: "myImage")
                .onTapGesture {
                   print("View Tapped")
                 }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationLink` should warped in `NavigationStack` like code below:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    NavigationLink {
      TheViewIWantNavigate()
    } label: {
      MyCustomView()
  }
}
```

If you want to explore more about navigation structures in SwiftUI, you can refer to Apple's sample code: “[Bringing robust navigation structure to your SwiftUI app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bringing_robust_navigation_structure_to_your_swiftui_app)”.

---

Remember the [`NavigationView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview?changes=latest_minor) will deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by using a state var as a toggle for a sheet.